# Is it possible to create a DLL of WCF Service which having webHttpBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll

I have searched over internet but did not get any specific answer or i say a satisfied answer that how can we make DLL of a WCF Service which is having webHttpBinding in its web.Config file.

I have a WCF Service which i want to deploy on client's server but i dont want them to see my code as if i host this service on their server they will able to see my code and i don't want that.

This Service responses in JSON Format which can be access only through URL.
so how to create a dll of this service and then host this on Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) A DLL does not have a web.config or any other .config.

2) Deploying a Service as a DLL does not prevent anyone from seeing the (disassembled) code.

3) You may be able to configure your service in code, but only when it's self-hosting. Which would usually be as an EXE, a DLL needs something else to host it.

Comment: okk then it means i have to create dll of my service code then host this with my web.config file on to the server.
m i getting right?

Comment: How will you be 'hosting' it ? Makes a lot of difference.

Comment: Actually this is of the client they are hosting this on IIS Server

Comment: In that case you deploy your code (DLL and SVC) and a config, yes. To a virtual directory, so create a Web Installer or a package. Including the sources is an option, make sure it's off.

Comment: "make sure it's off. "
how to do this will u please explain.. thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't remember all the steps/screens. Just go through the wizard and test before you ship it.

Comment: a DLL **can** have a config file. Or a link to the config file.